# How to call controller from jquery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to call my controller from view by Jquery which returns count. While debugging the result variable returns as undefined. Please someone correct my code.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.icon-delete').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var v = 'e8a6bdf4-1da6-41e0-8423-86ffacf71703';
       var result= GetCollectionCount(v);
        var answer = confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');
        if (answer) {
            $.post(this.href, function () {
                window.location.reload(); //Callback
            });
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
});

function GetCollectionCount(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: '/AdminNew/CollectionCount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "id": id },
        //traditional: true,
        success: function (ajaxresult) {
            //alert(ajaxresult);
            return ajaxresult;
        },
        failure: function (ajaxresult, status) {
            console.log(ajaxresult)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you're debugging, do you see the ActionResult method being called?

Comment: Can we see what your controler build for the ajax response ?

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult CollectionCount(string id)
        {
            FramesBusinessService.FramesBusinessSeviceClient client = new FramesBusinessService.FramesBusinessSeviceClient();
            FramesBusinessService.Counts cnt = client.Ser_GetCountsForBrandDelete(new Guid(id));    string s = string.Empty;
            if (cnt.collectioncount > 0 && cnt.framescount > 0)
            {
                s = cnt.collectioncount.ToString() + "Collecttions " + cnt.framescount.ToString() +"Frames";
            }
            }return Json(s,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: 1) Your call is ASYNC and result won't be equal to the request value 2)  It doesnt appear you are event using `result` so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> While debugging the result variable returns as undefined.

That's normal and is how AJAX works. The first **A** in **AJAX** stands for **Asynchronous**. This means that the `$.ajax` function doesn't return anything. It is used to trigger an AJAX request to the server and the **only single place** where you can use the results of this AJAX call is inside the `success` callback. In your example you seem to be attempting to use those results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `GetCollectionCount` is making an Asynchronous request to the server.  That is to say the rest of your code continues to execute and does not wait for the request to finish.

You need to place the code dependant on the request in a callback that is executed upon a successful request:

```
$(function () {
    $('.icon-delete').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var v = 'e8a6bdf4-1da6-41e0-8423-86ffacf71703';
        GetCollectionCount(v);
    });
});

function GetCollectionCount(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: '/AdminNew/CollectionCount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "id": id },
        //traditional: true,
        success: function (ajaxresult) {
            var answer = confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');
            if (answer) {
              $.post(this.href, function () {
                window.location.reload(); //Callback
              });
              return false;
            }
            return false;
        },
        error: function (ajaxresult, status) {
            console.log(ajaxresult)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: debugger not goes to the controller

Comment: My requirement is that I need to find out the count first, if count > 0 then it will not allow for delete and vice-versa.

Comment: @Laxminarayan also change `failure` to `error` in your ajax request.  That may fire the error callback and give us a message.  Also, you may want to post your routes and controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that :

```
$(function () {
    $('.icon-delete').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var v = 'e8a6bdf4-1da6-41e0-8423-86ffacf71703';
        GetCollectionCount(v);
    });
});

function GetCollectionCount(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: '/AdminNew/CollectionCount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "id": id },
        //traditional: true,
        success: getCollectionSuccess,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}

function getCollectionSuccess(ajaxResult){
    var answer = confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');
        if (answer) {
            $.post(this.href, function () {
                window.location.reload(); //Callback
            });
            return false;
       }
}

function errorCallback(errorMsg, status){
    console.log("Error Message : "+errorMsg+" Error code : "+status);
}
```

Comment: The problem may be in your controller. Can you link us your JSON response with firebug or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting `async` to false gets away the problem @Darin mentioned:

```
function GetCollectionCount(id) {
$.ajax({
    // ... your settings

    async: false,

    success: function (ajaxresult) {
        //alert(ajaxresult);
        return ajaxresult;
    },
    failure: function (ajaxresult, status) {
        console.log(ajaxresult)
    }
});
```

}